# Deploying app server-by-server vs. all at once

Tags: web-applications, deployment

Suppose I have a static JS single-page-app that I want to deploy to production, and there are 4 production servers.

1. I can deploy it to servers 1 & 2, try to test it, and then deploy to servers 3 & 4.
2. I can deploy it to all four servers at once.

Which one is more preferable and more common practice?

(1) requires sticky sessions to be set in my load balancer to prevent the user from receiving inconsistent files from two versions mid-deployment. I guess and advantage could be the ability to test on a portion of the servers first, but we would have already deployed and tested in our beta environment at that point, so I'm not sure this is important.

(2) Is simpler, but doesn't allow the above.

Is there ever a good reason to deploy an app consisting of static content only in multiple stages in one environment (prod)?

Comment: Option 2 is physically impossible, so you should always plan for rolling deployment...

Comment: Do you know what a good procedure is for doing a rolling deployment of a static client-side application without inconsistency or downtime?

Comment: Basic approach you likely already use may be all you need: version your js/css/jpg (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414/how-can-i-force-clients-to-refresh-javascript-files) and deploy HTML (linking to versioned js/css) changes at your own pace *after* assets deployed. Kind of hard to do anything simple than that, but you can always try to improve from there.